# How to disable colorbox for certain images

Tags: jquery, colorbox, pinterest

I have a page with some photo thumbs and they open in colorbox just fine.
The problem is beneath each thumb I have social icons - facebook, twitter, g+ and pintrest, and the pintrest image is considered part of the gallery.

How do I stop the pintrest image from getting included in the gallery display?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code  here, along with a fiddle if possible.http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you could try to use the icons as background images

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling the color box like below

```
$("img").colorbox()
```

instead

Give a class to all the images which you want to show on colobox () and then call the colorbox like below

```
$(".show-colorbox").colorbox()
```

Comment: Thank you Akbar! That was exactly it. I was calling the color box as
$('a', handler).colorbox(), so every link was getting added.